# MYSQL : How to see if a varchar exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, set, varchar

I was wondering if there was a way to check if a certain varchar from one table exists in another table without a join. I am currently updating a field in a temporary table based on if a name exists in another table. I have tried using =, like, and in but they don't seem to work.

Here my temp table is temp_countries and I want to see if each organization_name in countries exits in my database table organization.

```
UPDATE temp_countries SET is_good_data = 0
WHERE organization_name NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT o.name   
    FROM db.country as c
    LEFT JOIN db.organization as o
    ON c.organization_fk = o.id     
    WHERE o.name IS NOT NULL
);
```

I looked up maybe using GROUP_CONCAT but I wasn't sure it would work in this instance

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the join at all costs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a join in my query, so maybe you won't accept the answer, but I don't see why you wouldn't use a join, maybe what you really wanted to avoid was a subquery.

This is how I would do then. With joints:

- Set everything as "bad data"

  ```
  UPDATE temp_countries SET is_good_data = 0
  ```
- Then if a join is possible (implies o.name not null and exists in your DB), set it at "good data"

  ```
  UPDATE
      temp_countries tc
      INNER JOIN db.organization o o.name = tc.organization_name
      INNER JOIN db.country c ON c.organization_fk = o.id
  SET tc.is_good_data = 1
  ```

Now, if you truely have a personal grief against joints, please ignore my answer.